# Vuforia - Unity low image quality

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am using Vuforia with Unity for an Android AR app. I made it to take a screenshot of a specific area of the screen with the click of a button. It reads pixels in that specific area when the button is clicked.

The problem is, the resulting image is blurry/ low resolution. How can I increase the quality of the image?

I tried changing "Camera Device Mode" to "MODE_OPTIMIZE_QUALITY" and increasing "Number Divisions" in "Video Background" setting. But nothing happens. I also tried removing ARCore and changing "ARCore Requirement" to "DONT_USE" mode.

This is the code to take a snapshot :

```
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        //Get the corners of RectTransform rect and store it in a array vector
        Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
        _objToScreenshot.GetWorldCorners(corners);
        //Remove 100 and you will get error
        int width = ((int)corners[3].x - (int)corners[0].x) - 100;
        int height = (int)corners[1].y - (int)corners[0].y;
        var startX = corners[0].x;
        var startY = corners[0].y;
        //Make a temporary texture and read pixels from it
        Texture2D ss = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        ss.ReadPixels(new Rect(startX, startY, width, height), 0, 0);
        ss.Apply();

        //Save the screenshot to disk
        byte[] byteArray = ss.EncodeToPNG();
        string savePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss dd,MM, yyyy") + ".png";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, byteArray);
        //Debug.Log("Screenshot Path : " + savePath);
        // Destroy texture to avoid memory leaks
        Destroy(ss);
```

Comment: Can't you use this unity API? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I want to take a screenshot of a specific area of the screen. I don't want it to contain UI elements

Comment: Just to confirm that you want the "raw" camera image without any 2D UI element or 3D AR augmentation.